# Color border inverted

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a border with 2 two colors inside. The first color will be in blue and the next in white.

In my code, there is the colors which are inverted... The white before the blue... I don't understand why ?

```css
.border-color-blue{
  height: 182px;
  width: 260px;
  background-color: blue;

}
.border-white{
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  background: white;
  width: 260px;

}
```

```html
<div class="border-color-blue">
   <div class="border-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei cum option deserunt, sed cu dicta albucius dissentias.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: not clear what you want, but in case you have the opposite result, then switch the colors and you will have the intended result?

Comment: @ Temani Afif: Indeed, except that the text must be downstairs

Comment: can you show a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: @Temani Afif : for example like this https://imgur.com/a/WkMqTkD

Comment: it's a simple alignment issue then, check the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

This is all regular.

The whole container is blue.

Inside there is another container, with a white background.

To illustrate, added the `opacity` rule to `border-white`.

The one in forefront is hiding.

You can adjust which one end on top with the [z-index rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

```css
.border-color-blue{
  height: 182px;
  width: 260px;
  background-color: blue;

}
.border-white{
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  background: white;
  width: 260px;
  opacity: 0.7

}
```

```html
<div class="border-color-blue">
   <div class="border-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei cum option deserunt, sed cu dicta albucius dissentias.</div>
</div>
```